# Android Studioを起動するためにパスを通したいが今通そうとしているものであっているかがわからない

Tags: macos, android-studio

Android Studioが起動できず、以前このサイトでされていた質問を参考にやってみようと思ったのですが、パスというものに対する理解が浅いのでこれであっているかわからないのでお教え願いたいです。
機材はM1Macです

/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS